# QML: passing JS object to C++ member function

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to pass a JS object (map) to a C++ member function with a signature

```
Q_INVOKABLE virtual bool generate(QObject* context);
```

by using

```
a.generate({foo: "bar"});
```

The method is called (detected via breakpoint), but the passed `context` parameter is `NULL`. Since [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) mentions that JS objects will be passed as `QVariantMap`, I've tried using the signature

```
Q_INVOKABLE virtual bool generate(QVariantMap* context);
```

but this failed during MOC. Using

```
Q_INVOKABLE virtual bool generate(QVariantMap& context);
```

causes the method to not be found at runtime by QML (error message is "Unknown method parameter type: QVariantMap&").

The documentation only has an example of passing a `QVariantMap` from C++ to QML, not in the other direction.

Using a `public slot` instead of a `Q_INVOKABLE` shows exactly the same behavior and errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use references to pass values from QML world to CPP world.
This simple example works:

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariantMap>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(){}

    Q_INVOKABLE bool generate(QVariantMap context)
    {qDebug() << context;}
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("Test"), new Test());

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            Test.generate({foo: "bar"});
        }
    }
}
```

click in window, this will print following msg in output console:

```
QMap(("foo", QVariant(QString, "bar")))
```